# SQL Server optimal query based on value distribution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance, table-statistics

I have a table that stores dynamic user data in a key-value pair format. Something like this:

```
UserId | Key       | Value
---------------------------------
1      | gender    | male
1      | country   | Australia
2      | gender    | male
2      | country   | US
3      | gender    | female
3      | country   | Spain
```

Now, I need to select the users that have certain parameters, for example: gender is 'male' AND country is 'US'.  Or more general:

```
key1=value1 AND key2=value2 AND key3=value3 AND ...
```

To do so, the fastest way I found is to do the following:

```
WHERE key=(key1) 
AND   value=value1
AND   EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM (...)
             WHERE key=key2
             AND   value=value2)
AND   EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM (...)
             WHERE key=key3
             AND   value=value3)
AND   EXISTS(...)
```

In that case, I'll get the best result if the first WHERE filter is for the one whose values are more evenly and segregated.

For example, 'gender' can have 99% males and 1% females and country can partitionate the entire population in 100 similar parts.  In that case I would need to filter by country first and use EXIST for the gender condition.

**Question:**
Is there any way in SQL Server 2008 R2 to get the index statistics to find what clause is better to put first (not in the EXISTS basically) ?.

**Alternative question:** I think that that's the best approach, but a way to rewrite that query to be always optimal can be the solution too.

**SOLUTION INFORMATION:**

The correct solution is the one explained by @usr below (using `INTERSECT`). Actually it seems I was doing something wrong, the `EXISTS` was being resolved correctly too by the engine. To provide more info, I am sharing the IO and TIME statistics as well as the execution plan for the options tested:

Using `INTERSECT`:

```
Table 'PERFTEST'. Scan count 2, logical reads 113, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.
```

[image: Query plan using INTERSECT]

Using `EXISTS`:

```
Table 'PERFTEST'. Scan count 2, logical reads 113, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 3 ms.
```

[image: Query plan using EXISTS]

(Note the extra `Stream Aggregate` step)

Using `INNER JOIN`:

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'PERFTEST'. Scan count 2, logical reads 113, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 25 ms.
```

[image: Query plan using INNER JOIN]

**CONCLUSION:**

`INTERSECT` is slightly faster in this case that `EXISTS`. The `INNER JOIN` option is way slower.

Comment: Thanks @Tim3880, yes I'm assuming the sub queries you mentioned. I've just omitted the "AND sub.userid = table.userid" for simplicity.

Comment: @Tim3880 Thinking again, not sure that that assumption is wrong. Using `WHERE key=... and value=... and EXISTS(...)` produces results totally different than using 2 `EXISTS`.  Please note that I have a cluster index in key and value. (the rows returned are the same, the query plan and performance is difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "what clause is better to put first"

The optimizer does exactly that for you. Queries are not evaluated as written. `EXISTS` is translated to a join and undergoes the usual join reordering optimizations. Statistics are being used to drive that process. It's not perfect but usually good.

Use OPTION (RECOMPILE) to get a plan that is adjusted for the specific search parameters you are using.

---

```
select UserID from T where Condition1
intersect select UserID from T where Condition2
intersect select UserID from T where Condition3
```

Comment: I would say that that's not true.  Using `WHERE key=... and value=... and EXISTS(...)` produces results totally different than using 2 `EXISTS`.  Please note that I have a cluster index in key and value. (the rows returned are the same, the query plan and performance is difference)

Comment: OK, the optimizer seems to not do its job here. Try the query pattern that I just edited. If you want more analysis post actual query plans.

Comment: I think `INTERSECT` is the most appropriate and efficient way to do this kind of query.

Comment: Added my results in the question. The `intersect` option was the fastest.  Thank you!